# Variable as part of other variable php

Tags: php

I have a for script:

```
<?php for($i=1; $i<10; $i++):?>
<?php if($this->item->nuotrauka{$i}):?>
<div class="vobsmall">
<img src="<?php echo $this->item->nuotrauka{$i}; ?>"/>
<?php echo $this->item->nuotrauka{$i}; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

There's 9 variables like `$this->item->nuotrauka1`, `$this->item->nuotrauka2` etc.

As you can see here I'm trying to call these variables using `{i}` as number of object variable. Hovewer the code above returns single char from variable and not full variable as I want. How should I write `{i}` here to get what I want ?

Comment: Why are you using variables named like this instead of using an array?

Comment: Having to use dynamic variables can be a sign for bad design somewhere. As Barmar said, you probably want to use an array instead.

Comment: Just make a variable in each loop. Like so: $node = 'nuotrauka' . $i; and then when you display it: $this->item->$node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo $this->item->{"nuotrauka".$i};
```

Comment: Doesn't `nuotrauka` have to be a string?

Comment: (I mean, it does work, but more accidentally. You'd get a notice like `Notice: Use of undefined constant nuotrauka - assumed 'nuotrauka' in /foo.php on line xyz`)